# How to reuse and share an HTTP connection between multiple threads in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

In an IPhone app, I want to create a connection, have the user log in to a webservice once, and then have all subsequent requests by multiple threads reuse the authorized connection. What is the best way to implement this in iOS?

FYI: I have implemented this previously in an Android app by using Apache HTTPClient with a threadSafeConnectionManager whereby whenever you need a connection, you ask the shared httpClient for one and it dispatches one from the pool it maintains; all connections retain the same authentication credentials. I am looking for the comparable way to do this in an IPhone app.

Comment: Isn't this a bit of a misuse of the HTTP protocol? How did you implement that on the server side?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a 'misuse'. And, there is nothing about this implemented on the server side, this concept is for a client application such as an IPhone app or an Android app.  It is the same idea as a web browser sending multiple requests to a server that appear to be coming from the same client.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any built in mechanism for this, but you could fork [ASIHttpRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree) and bend it to your will.  It shouldn't take much effort to refactor the authentication part from a shared location, but your concept of reusing the TCP socket may take a bit of work.  There probably isn't a way of doing it with `NSURLRequest`, but since `ASIHttpRequest` uses the core foundation methods, that is not an issue.